# Independence, question using a simple example

Tags: probability, independence

I have a question about event independence.  I have the following example in which $A$ and $B$ are independent.  Consider rolling a 6 sided die:

$A=\{1,2\}$

$B=\{2,4,6\}$

$P(A) = 1/3, P(B) = 1/2$

$P(A \cap B) = 1/6 = P(A)P(B)$

so $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Now, if I change $B$ to:

$B=\{2,4,6,3\}$

$P(A) = 1/3, P(B) = 4/6 = 2/3$

$P(A \cap B) \ne P(A)P(B)$,
$1/6 \ne 2/9$

Now $A$ and $B$ are no longer independent given this single element change.

How does adding the single element $3$, other then by the definition of independence being $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ change whether $A$ and $B$ are independent?  I don't see how event $A$ or $B$ causes a change in probability of the other event.  I'm basically trying to understand if there is some general intuitive rule I should be following to determine independent events other then substituting them into this formula?

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for...$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is the definition of independence. Equivalently (more or less) $P(A\,|\,B)=P(A)$ and that's the one that's most useful here, I'd say...since it is clearly that, in the first instance, knowing that $B$ happened still leaves us with a $\frac 13$ chance that $A$ happened, but in the second instance, knowing that $B$ happened leaves us a $\frac 14$ chance that $A$ happened.

Comment: As a rule, I'd say that intuition was not a very reliable way of approaching statistical phenomena.  It's good to have the definitions to fall back on.

Comment: I'm trying to see how one event would impact the probability of the other.  I don't see it with or without the change.  That is where I'm confused.

Comment: In some example in my text, non-independence is claimed by indicating that one event impacts the probability of another without use of sets.  Then here, the definition is used with set theory.  I'm confused upon what approach should be taken.

Comment: Always fall back on the definition.  Sometimes intuition enables us to cut through to an answer, but more often, I'd say, the situation is simply not clear and in those cases we should use the definition.  It's a standard error, amongst those who use Statistics informally, to argue that two events are "obviously independent" because the author can not imagine a connection...but the world is more complex than that author's imagination and sometimes there are surprising dependencies.  My favorite is that the homicide rate in big cities is linked to ice cream consumption (because of the heat).

Comment: Thanks.  I notice that my probability course and even Casella and Berger will often make the connection without creating a set theoretic definition of sample space perhaps with the cartesian product, which is required to use this definition of independence, same with conditional probabilities.  Is this typical?

Comment: Yes, that is typical.  The reader is expected to create their own sample spaces.